# Edit account creation message

Tags: users

I'm trying to change the message users see after creating an account. It currently says:

*Thank you for applying for an account. Your account is currently pending approval by the site administrator.
In the meantime, a welcome message with further instructions has been sent to your e-mail address.*

What's the best way of changing this? Would the String Overrides module help? A Rule, perhaps?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what the [String Overrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module is for.

If you only need just a couple strings, you can also use `settings.php`.  See this section:

```
/**
 * String overrides:
 *
 * To override specific strings on your site with or without enabling locale
 * module, add an entry to this list. This functionality allows you to change
 * a small number of your site's default English language interface strings.
 *
 * Remove the leading hash signs to enable.
 */
```

You don't want to use Rules, because although you can add a new message with a rule, the old message will still be there as well (which isn't what you want, I assume).

Comment: Thanks for your help, Patrick. I'm trying my hardest to resist editing setting.php! Is this right? http://i.imgur.com/SVkS40N.png

Comment: It is worth noting that the string overrides module needs the exact text including the line breaks in the orginal message. See https://www.drupal.org/node/1261668

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with Rule module because this module was already used in my application but as Patrick Kenny said we can set new message with a rule but the old message will still be there as well. This problem I solved with the help of CSS (hiding message div with display:none property).

Comment: hm, how about further improving your rule, so that you would not need any CSS tweaks, and which should work for any theme also?

Answer (score -3):

You can change those messages in Configuration>Account settings (admin/config/people/accounts).
There is E-mails section where you can change messages used during account registeration process.

Comment: The OP is not talking about emails they are wishing to remove the on-screen notification